# Search library path while adding multiple third party SDK in Xcode 6

Tags: ios, sdk, path, xcode6

In my project I need to add Google analytics SDK and AdMob SDK. Each works fine when I add them separately. When I add them together it shows an error message as in the picture 
[image]

When I googled about this issue I found that the issue is related with Search library path(at least I think so). After adding both SDK my search path library looks like this
[image]

How to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the issue. Actually I need to import `libsqlite3.0.dylib`. But google docs doesn’t mention about it .

Answer (score 1):

`$(PROJECT_DIR)/`

Represent your `project root folder` and now you have to add `path` for `library file`.

- You can add `multiple path` with tapping on `Plus` button.
- Suppose in `project` you putted your `lib file` in `Temp Directory` then `path` will be

`$(PROJECT_DIR)/ Temp`